# gluLookAt First person View

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to switch my space invaders game to a first person view, i.e. a view of the world from the ship. I am getting a bit confused about what point I should be looking at. I am currently using these parameters in gluLookAt:

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GLU.gluLookAt(ship3dPos.x, ship3dPos.y, ship3dPos.z,400.0f, 600.0f,-50.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,-0.0f);
```

Im not sure what I'm supposed to set parameters 4,5 and 6 to, to get a view of the whole world(window is 800/600).

Comment: Where do you *want* the ship to look? Is it looking straight up, or to the right, or at a particular target? If you want it to look at a target, what is the position of that target?

Comment: I want it to basically have a first person view upwards towards the aliens which are at around 500 on the y-axis. I want this view to then move right and left when the player moves the ship i.e. + or - on the x axis. So moving to the left would allow aliens that are more to the left to be seen etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a first person view then params 0 1 2 will be the player, 3 4 5 will be where they are looking and 6 7 8 will be upwards.

gluLookAt(eye.x,eye.y,eye.z,center.x,center.y,center.z,up.x,up.y,up.z)

Up vector - defines what "up" is for the view [image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarification in your comment, you want the x-coordinate of the point you look at (`centerx`) to change with the position of your ship. So that should probably be the same as `ship3dPos.x`.

One thing that we still need to figure out is the z-depth of the ship and of the aliens. I'm going to assume that they are equal for now in which case `centerz` is going to be that depth. If they are not equal then we need to do a little more math and the answer for `centery` below will change slightly.

You say you want to look 'up' toward the aliens, so you need a greater y-value than `ship3dPos.y`. Remember that the 'lookAt' point can be any point along the line of sight, so (again, assuming the depths are the same) `ship3dPos.y+1.0` will work, or if you're happy with the estimate of 500 as the y-position of the aliens you could use that too. Basically, as long as the depths are the same and the y-position of the aliens is greater than that of the ship you can use anything greater than `ship3dPos.y`.

With the above assumptions, your 'lookAt' vector (centerx, centery, centerz) would be:

```
ship3dPos.x, ship3dPos.y+1.0, ship3dPos.z
```

But there's one more component in your gluLookAt() call that needs attention: the `up` vector. If we leave the `up` vector as (0,1,0) you're still going to be looking directly into the screen. I'm going to assume that what you really want is to look along the plane of the screen (the x-y plane), in which case `up` should be in the z-direction and the up vector would be:

```
0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
```

Give that a try and see if it does what you think it should.